# D3 Transition: Rotation and Translation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm brand new to d3 and I like it so far, but I'm trying to put something together and can't figure out how to correct certain behaviors.

Here's a demo of what I'm trying to do:

[Removed] deadlink

The first behavior is that the "starting" point for each gauge always defaults back to black and colors transition from there.

The second behavior is that the transition between rotations "bounces". This is because it is not rotating around (150,150) but instead rotating around (0,0) which makes it "bounce" in the transition, but I have no clue how to fix this.

Can someone please help me see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both behaviors are the result that you are resetting the current state of the gauge on every redraw.  Try taking out the lines:

```
pointer
  .attr("transform", null)
  .style("fill", null);
```

The transform takes the gauge back to the origin and the fill takes it back to black.

Comment: That solved the first problem. Thanks. It still bounces though and I updated the site to show the current code. Any ideas on that one? I think it has to do with rotating and translating.

Answer (score 0):

This function will fix the bounce. I needed an interpolation function to remove the bouncing.
a is the prior position.

```
pointer.transition()
        .style("fill", this.valueToColor(value))
        .duration(1000)
        .ease("bounce")
        .attrTween("transform", tween);

    function tween(d, i, a) {
      return d3.interpolateString(a, "rotate(" + rotateAngle + ", 150, 150)");
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you got it... congrats.